# The Stack Exchange "Log In" button is hard to see

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com

When I visit StackExchange.com, the "Log In" button at the top of the page has bad contrast against the background color of the top nav bar. I can only see it when I hover over the link.

I am using Firefox as my browser. Here is a screenshot of how the link looks when not being hovered over.

[image]

Can the contrast on this please be adjusted?

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the Top Bar has been redesigned with [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/), but the relevant CSS files are missing.

Inspecting the "Log In" button, it already has `class="s-topbar--item s-topbar--item__unset s-btn s-btn__filled ws-nowrap js-gps-track"` set, with `s-btn` and `s-btn__filled` for [styling the button](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/buttons/). However, the rules for them are not found.

Cross checking the rules with a button from a working site (e.g. "Ask Question" button on Meta Stack Exchange) shows that `s-btn` loads from `/Content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/primary.css`, and there is also `/Content/Shared/stacks.css`, which both of them are missing on the Stack Exchange homepage.

By experimenting, adding both CSS files *before* the existing CSS files will fix the issue, though it also breaks other layouts...

[image]